# Garbled characters encountered when decompiling Lua

Tags: lua, decompiling, unluac

The lua file was from an apk using **luajava** and **andlua**, lua version seems to be **5.3.3**

After I used **unluac** to decompile and obtain the lua file, I found that all the strings became garbled characters.

```lua
local L0_0, L1_1, L2_2, L3_3, L4_4, L5_5, L6_6, L7_7
L0_0 = _ENV
L1_1 = L0_0["]$"]
L2_2 = L0_0["u\229\136\006\133\020\186"]
L3_3 = "u\v\138\027\133\002"
L2_2 = L2_2(L3_3)
L3_3 = L0_0["u\229\136\006\133\020\186"]
L4_4 = "i\020\1460"
L3_3 = L3_3(L4_4)
L4_4 = L0_0["u\229\136\006\133\020\186"]
L5_5 = "x\230k\237`\247,\227\145\015\158"
L4_4 = L4_4(L5_5)
L5_5 = L4_4
function L6_6(A0_8, A1_9, A2_10, A3_11)
  local L4_12
  L4_12 = L0_0
  return L4_4["d\030\181(\213x\241"](A0_8, A1_9, A2_10, A3_11, "m\031\1878")
end
L5_5["k\028\176$\208B\248\195"] = L6_6
function L6_6(A0_13, A1_14, A2_15, A3_16)
  local L4_17
  L4_17 = L0_0
  return L4_4["d\030\181(\213x\241"](A0_13, A1_14, A2_15, A3_16, "l\029\132$\136")
end
L5_5["k\028\176$\208B\248\193"] = L6_6
function L6_6(A0_18, A1_19, A2_20)
  local L3_21, L4_22, L5_23, L6_24, L7_25
  L3_21 = L0_0
  if A0_18 == "+" then
    A0_18 = "7\016E\130\2115b"
  end
  L4_22 = L4_4["g\004\162"]
  L4_22 = L4_22["l\024\155\003\176#\203E\240w\236"]
  L5_23 = A0_18
  L5_23 = L4_22(L5_23)
  if not L4_22 then
    L6_24 = nil
    L7_25 = L5_23
    return L6_24, L7_25
  end
  L6_24, L7_25 = nil, nil
  L5_23 = "|\2533\250z\242z\181y\2487\246|\252k\252i\233"
  for _FORV_11_, _FORV_12_ in L1_1["o\005\133=\177@"](L4_22) do
    if _FORV_12_["`\019\179\"\219]"] == "m\031\1878" then
      L6_24, L5_23 = L4_4["p\031\132Y"]()
    else
      L6_24, L5_23 = L4_4["p\031\132["]()
    end
    if not L6_24 then
      return nil, L5_23
    end
    L6_24["z\224v\017\138\003\154\031\130"](L6_24, "{\225u\b\147\019\137\r\150", true)
    L7_25, L5_23 = L6_24["f\003\190S"](L6_24, _FORV_12_["e\r\170F"], A1_19)
    if not L7_25 then
      L6_24["f\001\186M\195"](L6_24)
    else
      L7_25, L5_23 = L6_24["j\017\153)\170,"](L6_24, A2_20)
      if not L7_25 then
        L6_24["f\001\186M\195"](L6_24)
      else
        return L6_24
      end
    end
  end
  return nil, L5_23
end
```

I tried hard to find the original file of one of the lua files on the Internet, and found that all the strings and methods had become garbled characters.

```lua
local base = _G
local string = require("string")
local math = require("math")
local socket = require("socket.core")

local _M = socket

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Exported auxiliar functions
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function _M.connect4(address, port, laddress, lport)
    return socket.connect(address, port, laddress, lport, "inet")
end

function _M.connect6(address, port, laddress, lport)
    return socket.connect(address, port, laddress, lport, "inet6")
end

function _M.bind(host, port, backlog)
    if host == "*" then host = "0.0.0.0" end
    local addrinfo, err = socket.dns.getaddrinfo(host);
    if not addrinfo then return nil, err end
    local sock, res
    err = "no info on address"
    for i, alt in base.ipairs(addrinfo) do
        if alt.family == "inet" then
            sock, err = socket.tcp4()
        else
            sock, err = socket.tcp6()
        end
        if not sock then return nil, err end
        sock:setoption("reuseaddr", true)
        res, err = sock:bind(alt.addr, port)
        if not res then
            sock:close()
        else
            res, err = sock:listen(backlog)
            if not res then
                sock:close()
            else
                return sock
            end
        end
    end
    return nil, err
end
```

The Luas file

```
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
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how I can get the normal source files?

Comment: Please upload the original file (Lua bytecode) you are trying to decompile. It might happen that this file is additionally obfuscated.

Comment: What version of Lua was that code compiled with?

Comment: It looks like strings are encrypted. This seems non-standard, (I think luajava just links against native PUC-Rio Lua. Andlua looks like a Lua port, but I didn't see a bytecode loader (and would doubt an open source project would add encryption like this anyway)). You would have to break the encryption via cryptanalysis or reverse engineering an application that can do the decryption. (Also debugging information is stripped which unluac is bad at handling, but that has nothing to do with the strings.)

Comment: @tehtmi Thank you so much. I rechecked the apk and indeed found an encryption function.